# Is it just my imagination or have the fonts gotten even uglier?

Tags: discussion, design

The fonts (including the preview font I see below while typing this) seem to be "blotchier" this morning, as viewed on Firefox 35.0.1 atop Vista.  Capital F and T have doubled top bars, among other things.

> [image]

In this second image note the blips on the top of C, Q, G, and S.

> [image]

**Resolved:**

Installed the fix from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3037639 and everything is hunky-dory again.

Comment: Use a lossless image format like png. Can't judge rendering quality from a screenshot saved as a lossy jpg.

Comment: Are you sure your browser's zoom level is at 100%?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Yep..

Comment: OK, I am seeing the same thing on a minority of the fonts used by BBC, so presumably it's a Mozilla font thing.  (Loaded Microsoft fixes yesterday -- I wonder it that had something to do with it?)

Comment: What font is the browser rendering? Try CTRL+SHIFT+C in firefox, click on an element, and click on the Fonts tab.

Comment: Yup - truly ugly text on FF 35.0.1, Vista 64  :(

Comment: The redesign uses Helvetica Neue, which some Windows applications will try to remap to Arial even if Helvetica Neue is installed on the system, and others, well... they don't. And Helvetica Neue is not known for looking pretty in body copy size on Windows. It almost seems deliberate.

Comment: However I'm not entirely sure I would assume Helvetica Neue is installed on your system... or is it?

Comment: @BoltClock Check out [how this Bootstrap user feels about it.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13823) I'm on Linux and I don't have Helvetica Neue, luckily my system's defaults are pretty good.

Comment: @remyabel - It's showing Arial, Arial Bold, and Gulim.  (Never heard of Gulim before.)  Doesn't seem to zero in on a specific font when I click on specific text.

Comment: Control Panel => Fonts doesn't list any Helvitica.

Comment: @HotLicks - yeah, I got the same font info.

Comment: You could try fiddling with, err, I mean optimising for your system, the type rendering parameters with [Firefox Anti-Aliasing Tuner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/).

Comment: @BoltClock, in my case, I have installed Helvetica Neue Light, and the font looks terrible after it, what do I need to do to get around this?

Comment: Did you say… vista?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/528/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There have been quite a few off topic questions about this at SO.  At issue is the KB3013455 security update that was released on February 10th.  Microsoft is aware of the font rendering problem this can cause and is working on a fix.

Sample Mozilla bug report [is here](https://support.mozilla.org/bs/questions/1046333).  There are a *ton* of web pages about it already, you can find them by googling "KB3013455 breaks fonts".  Simplest workaround is to uninstall the update.

Update: they fixed it, the download [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3037639).

Comment: Thanks.  Hard to believe that a SECURITY fix could mess up the fonts, but I gather that this security bug is an odd one.  And it's good to know that I'm not going crazy (at least not on this account) -- the bug really did appear "overnight", after installing the updates yesterday.

Comment: http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-0059

Comment: Ah, so the security bug is a font injection vulnerability!!

Comment: One might fear to open a plain text file these days.

Comment: They have a [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/30376390).

Comment: @PaulDraper - Bad link.

Comment: Apparently this is the good link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3037639

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue last year when Open Sans became popuplar. At least that's when I first noticed it. You need to turn on ClearType on your Operating System.

You'll find instructions here for XP, Vista, 7, 8 and 8.1:

https://www.winhelp.us/change-font-smoothing-in-windows.html

Don't forget to restart after

Comment: It appears that ClearType is already enabled on Vista.

Comment: Except this isn't Open Sans. Helvetica Neue just looks that bad on Windows - *even with ClearType*.

Comment: @BoltClock ClearType may not be enabled in Firefox.

Comment: Apparently what has happened is that the "fix" has disabled ClearType completely.  It may be marked enabled, but it's not.

Comment: I just noticed the difference and in fact it got better (Mac).